# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'PositiveIntegerField' and 'int'

Tags: python, django-models

Hello I am having a problem which I guess is really simple. I have the following class:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    nominal_power = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    module_nominal_power= models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def calculation_of_components(a, b):
        return int((a*1000)/b)

    no_modules=calculation_of_components(nominal_power,module_nominal_power)
```

and I get the error: 
`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'PositiveIntegerField' and 'int'`

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: one way is you could convert `PositiveIntegerField` back to `int`: `nominal_power = int(models.PositiveIntegerField())` `module_nominal_power= int(models.PositiveIntegerField())`

Comment: Just cast them to integers: `( int(a) * 1000 ) / int(b)`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're calling `calculation_of_components` at the creation time of the model class, when the fields have yet to take any value.

You can solve this by making `no_modules` a **[`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property)** so `calculation_of_components` does not get called at the creation of the model class, when the fields have no value:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    nominal_power = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    module_nominal_power = models.PositiveIntegerField()

    def calculation_of_components(self, a, b):
        return int((a*1000)/b)

    @property
    def no_modules(self):
        return self.calculation_of_components(self.nominal_power, self.module_nominal_power)
```

You can then access `no_modules` like a regular model field:

```
plnt = Plant(...)
plnt.no_modules
```

<sub>Pro-Tip: you can use integer division `//` in your calculation and avoid calling `int`: `a * 1000 // b`</sub>

Comment: I tried your solution but when I try to call no_modules in my views.py         **plants = Plant.objects.filter(user=request.user)**
**total_no_modules = Plant.objects.filter(user=request.user).aggregate(sum=Sum('plants.no_modules'))** I get **Exception Type: FieldError**

Comment: @George You can use it as you would a model field. If you want to you can define it as an `IntegerField` and assign its value when you're saving the model.

Comment: how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

First: `calculation_of_components` is a static method of class.

In your code `no_modules` is a result of function `calculation_of_components`. Probably You need a function:

```
class Plant(models.Model):
    nominal_power = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    module_nominal_power= models.PositiveIntegerField()

    @staticmethod    
    def calculation_of_components(a, b):
        return int((a*1000)/b)

    def no_modules(self):
        return self.calculation_of_components(self.nominal_power, self.module_nominal_power)
```

Answer (score -1):

This error means the type of objects you're trying to multiply (*) are different objects, you cannot multiply `PositiveIntegerField` with `int`. You mixed `PositiveIntegerField` object with `int` object. You can make `PositiveIntegerField` appears in multiplication expressions by defining `__mul__` operator overloading method in your class so when an instance of `PositiveIntegerField` appears with multiplication expression Python automatically overloads `__mul__` method. In python 2.X `__coerce__` gets called when different types of objects appear in such expressions in order to coerce them to a common type. Though, the use of `__coerce__` isn't recommended.

Some classes that may be used in mathematical operations use `__int__` to return an integer representing their values when needed:

```
class Num:
    def __int__(self):
        return self.value

int(Num()) * 20
```

Comment: Did I get anything wrong in my answer? I see a down vote.